# Use the Shrinkwrap modifier to form a skin over a collection of objects

Tags: modifiers, vertex-groups

I'm trying to use the Shrinkwrap modifier to form a skin over a collection of objects, but:

- I have to provide a single target object. I'd rather keep the objects separate, but I could put them all into the same vertex group?
- In which case, how can I apply all vertices of all selected objects to a vertex group at once?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. Not the way you're looking at it anyway. However, this *might* be a viable solution. If you're trying to do this in the editor (rather than in the BGE) you could create a single duplicate of each of the objects you want to wrap around. Merge them together. Wrap your cloth or what have you around the duplicated/merged version of your objects. Apply the modifier. Delete the duplicate version. Move your cloth to the objects.

If you're trying to do this in the BGE I'm not sure it's possible without manipulating verts in script.